# Brew: Newly installed package, command not found

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon, zsh, ventura

I've tried installing xxhash with brew, but I keep getting

```
zsh: command not found: xxhash
```

I ran brew doctor until I was ready to brew, reinstalled brew and the package, I added all the bins to my path and am at my wits end, other packages run clean. Between all steps I restarted the terminal.

```
% echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I have the latest of Ventura on a M1 Mac, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command `xxhash` installed by this package. The binary is called `xxhsum` and is in your `PATH`.

```sh
$ ll /opt/homebrew/Cellar/xxhash/0.8.1/bin
total 184
lrwxr-xr-x  1 verence  wheel      6 Nov 29  2021 xxh128sum@ -> xxhsum
lrwxr-xr-x  1 verence  wheel      6 Nov 29  2021 xxh32sum@ -> xxhsum
lrwxr-xr-x  1 verence  wheel      6 Nov 29  2021 xxh64sum@ -> xxhsum
-rwxr-xr-x  1 verence  wheel  92131 Nov 29  2021 xxhsum*
$ type xxhsum
xxhsum is /opt/homebrew/bin/xxhsum
```

Comment: Aw man, I am a giddy goat, thanks for clearing this up!